# BGE register new Action

Tags: game-engine, fcurves

I wanted, for a game with level editing capabilities, to create an Action (animation fcurves) from scratch and assign it to an existing Action actuator.

However, when the Action is created at runtime (or at least in the same script and in the same use of it), it will​ not be recognised as existing when its name is assigned to the actuator's "action" variable
Does anyone know how to register the action in order to make it usable?
Thanks in advance

Comment: As far as I know the BGE does not support creating actions. How did you create it?

Comment: I... Launched the game built in the programme window, not in another one. I also discovered that my script crashed sooner in standalone: importing bpy failed.

Comment: Downvote my question to -3 because it is irrelevant, I guess

Comment: You can not use bpy with bge, bpy only work with blender itself, that's why in standalone it fail. About your question i just dont understand, maybe you are creating a curve in game(?) using bpy and trying to assing it as a new action wich any way will fail because once loaded the actions of an object in bge (from the .blend file) you can not change them in bge (i think).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't create actions with the BGE. Animations needs to be present in the blend, a linked blend, or loaded blend (via LibLoad).

## Background

You used `bpy` - which is the API to Blender. Be aware Blender is only available when you run your game session embedded inside Blender. Typically you do not deliver Blender with your game.

When you run the game session embedded inside Blender creating an action, it is only present in Blender (-> bpy is talking with Blender, not with the BGE). The running game session will not know about it. Any change made by Blender will not be recognized by the game session, as everything is loaded already.

**For better imagination:**

Imagine your game session is a car the player is driving. 
The BlenderPlayer is the factory that creates a new car from a blue print.
The .blend file is the blue print. 
Blender is the construction office that created the blue prints.

When you modify the blue prints while you are driving the car the car will not change. You will need to create a new car from the modified blue prints.

So you stop the car you are sitting in. Then you let the factory create a new car and start that one.

Back to the BGE: You stop your game session and start a new one. Then you see the modifications.

Comment: I will have to find a way around it. I will post it here, too